# Rendered SBS (side by side) video, but only left (_L) side is created

Tags: rendering, video, stereoscopy

I have created a very simple 3D animation from cube and rendered SBS video, but only left (_L) video is created.

I've made the cube to turn in 250 frames, it works OK.
I've set side-by-side with Ogg Theora.
Rendering the animation works fine, the video file (3d0001-0250_L.ogv) is created in the given directory.
But this file contains only the left side.
What have I missed?
How can I get the right side?

Comment: Additional info: if I create anaglyph, then I get _L and _R videos as well.

Comment: Unfortunately it happened only one time that _L and _R videos were created in parallel. For each other try only _L if both left and right checkboxes were checked. If I've checked only right checkbox, then _R video was created.

Comment: It just happened after many tries, that it created only one video, named _L  without prefix and extension, but it contains both the left and right sides. I have not done anything what I have not tried previously, so I don't know the reason.